# how to silently adjust system volume?

Tags: 12.04, sound, volume-control, indicator-sound

I am using 12.04 LTS. Is there a way to properly disable that feedback sound when you are adjusting the volume? I would like to adjust the volume on my system without producing those "pops".

Unfortunately [this old thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/61878/how-can-i-disable-the-popping-sound-when-adjusting-the-volume) did not produce any answers that are useful for my situation, since disabling **all** notification sounds impacts the use of many applications.