# How to disable the popping sound when changing the volume in KDE/Kubuntu?

Tags: sound, kubuntu

I've just upgraded Kubuntu from 12.04 to 14.04, and (as expected) there are several annoyances. The first one I've tried and failed to solve is the "popping" sound that is played whenever I change the volume, with the mixer or with the volume keys. I have enough with the OSD, I don't want any sound.

I have "no audio" selected in the notifications setting, but that doesn't help.

Something else I've noticed, and don't remember it was like this before: when a system tray menu is displaying, the volume keys do not work...

Comment: Note to those that marked as close, this is not a bug, this is a sound feature that the user wants to remove. When you change the volume it makes a pop sound. It is actually annoying and that is what the OP wants to disable.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Press Alt+F2 keys. A small text box will appear at top margin in center of screen with few icons. Type `kmix`. And now there will be a option of KMix with its logo. Click on it. And look in notification area there should be broadcasting speaker; click on it.You get dialog box with few buttons Select the button with Spanner on it. A window will open named "Configure KMix". In that window on left hand there will be General option. In General option you will uncheck the "Volume Feedback". close window. Right click on speaker in notification area select Quit. And restart KMix as described above. This should solve your problem.

Comment: Ah... thanks. I had done all this (except kmix was already running, so no need to launch it), but didn't try closing and reopening kmix, I thought "Apply" would be enough. (And, maybe because of my KDE translation, it was not very clear what this particular setting was supposed to do, so when I disabled it and it didn't work I assumed it meant something else.)

Comment: outdated - the other answer should be marked

Answer (score 21):

*The trouble with GUI-based answer is that they can't be trusted for too long...*

Right-click on the tray icon:

[image]

Click on "Audio Volume Settings... Alt+D, S".

Disable "Volume feedback" (i.e., the button should be gray, not blue).

[image]

## Version info:

```
~$ plasmashell --version
plasmashell 5.8.6
~$ kf5-config --version
Qt: 5.7.1
KDE Frameworks: 5.28.0
kf5-config: 1.0
```

Comment: Note: As of 2020, this option is now named "Provide visual feedback: ☑ When volume changes. It still controls the audio feedback as per this answer.

Comment: @DDR : I can't get it removed even after unchecking those boxes.

Comment: Dang. It must have been a combination of that and something else, then.

Answer (score 3):

As the new versions of KDE4 (not to mention Plasma5) have some changes in the GUI of settings, another way is the one posted in [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/90580/32012) answer.

The first solution there for KDE4 (System Settings > Common Appearance and Behaviour > Application and System Notifications > Manage Notifications > Player Settings > No audio output) didn't completely worked for me.

That may or may not be related to [this bug](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=301836).

Anyway, specifically  for **disabling the sound heard when changing the volume**: click the volume tray icon and disable Event Sounds:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

*The trouble with GUI-based answer is that they can't be trusted for too long... (bis)*

Right-click on the tray icon:

[image]

Click on "Audio Volume Settings... Alt+D, S".

Uncheck "Audio Volume" in front of "Play audio feedback for changes to:".

[image]

## Version info:

```
~$ plasmashell --version
plasmashell 5.27.5
```

KDE Frameworks
Version 5.103.0