# Can I control the System volume with a keyboard shortcut that works everywhere?

Tags: shortcut-keys, volume-control

Can I control the System volume with a keyboard shortcut that works everywhere?

I hate having to change the way I turn up/down the volume. I'd like to always do that from keyboard. Is that possible? (I mean something quick such as Key up / key down)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure you can.

Go to System Settings -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts -> Sound and Media

[image]

Now you can do what I did and choose `Ctrl+UP` for volume up and `Ctrl+Down` for volume down, or you can choose any other shortcut that suits you best.

Comment: I did it with Ctrl-Up/Ctrl-Down (Ctrl-M for Mute). It works perfect. Thank you. Just bothers me the small sound when pressing those keys. Can I get rid of it?

Comment: @ShirleyTemple I don't know about that. I like the sound :))
But this guy has the same [problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/61878/how-can-i-disable-the-popping-sound-when-adjusting-the-volume). check it out.