# Disable sound effect when Adjust volume with hotkeys

Tags: 18.04

I want to disable this annoying sound of increasing / decreasing the sound when I use the keys). Only him, all the other sound notifications leave. Ubuntu 18, the gnome. 
I saw same questions from 2009-2013 years, but it disable all sound effects.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I disable the "popping" sound when adjusting the volume?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/61878/how-can-i-disable-the-popping-sound-when-adjusting-the-volume)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following in the command line:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.sound event-sounds false
```

Comment: thanks i did it before with dconf-editor. but now my stupid ubuntu try to decrease or increase volume on another source sound chanel. i mean i push FN+Volume- but sounds keep going on 100 percent. 18.04 is full sh** :) Need every time to set sound chanel after reboot. and btw this command disable all sound effects no?

Comment: Try this article: https://askubuntu.com/questions/61878/how-can-i-disable-the-popping-sound-when-adjusting-the-volume/152357

Comment: # mv /usr/share/sounds/freedesktop/stereo/audio-volume-change.oga /usr/share/sounds/freedesktop/stereo/audio-volume-change.oga.backup
# cp silent.ogg /usr/share/sounds/freedesktop/stereo/audio-volume-change.oga
# reboot now

Comment: This command has no effect (after logging out and back in again) for GNOME 3.30.2 on Manjaro.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 18:

```
mv /usr/share/sounds/freedesktop/stereo/audio-volume-change.oga /usr/share/sounds/freedesktop/stereo/audio-volume-change.oga.backup
```

Ubuntu 19:

```
mv /usr/share/sounds/Yaru/stereo/audio-volume-change.oga /usr/share/sounds/Yaru/stereo/audio-volume-change.oga.backup
```

Then just reboot.