# How to enable volume adjust sound effect for keyboard shortcuts on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: sound, keyboard, shortcut-keys, pulseaudio, alsa

This question is related to [How can I disable the "popping" sound when adjusting the volume?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/61878/how-can-i-disable-the-popping-sound-when-adjusting-the-volume/152357) in that I want to fully **enable** the popping sound for all methods of adjusting the volume, particularly keyboard shortcuts (e.g. FN keys).

After some sound issues I had to reinstall the pulseaudio package.
While the original problem was solved, I noticed a change in the system sound effects:

If I adjust the volume via the combinations FN+F3 (volume down) or FN+F4 (volume up), the volume adjustment is **not** accompanied by the popping sound anymore.

The 'popping' sound effect does still occur, however, if I adjust the volume by clicking on the volume slider.

Things I tried that did not resolve the problem:

1. Enabling/disabling "Altert Volume" in Settings>Sound>Sound Effects
2. Reinstalling `alsa-base` and `pulseaudio`.
3. `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.sound event-sounds true` (analogous to https://askubuntu.com/a/63687/589172)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the exact same issue and reinstalled the same packages as you. Eventually, I got things working again by installing `libcanberra-pulse` which had somehow been uninstalled.

`libcanberra` is a "simple abstract interface for playing event sounds".
https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/libcanberra-pulse

Answer (score 0):

After reinstalling Ubuntu, the original popping sound and sound setting behavior have been restored.

I could not figure out a proper way to fix the problem and reinstalling was the more time-efficient way in the end.

I'd still be very happy to find a proper way to solve such problem in the future, though.