# Volume Up/Down alert sound notification

Tags: 20.04

I have just updated from Ubuntu 19 to 20.04 and one thing is not working or missing is the notification sound when you are changing the volume using the hotkeys.

I really used that a lot even for checking if my sound was playing in the speakers or headsets.

I have Alert Sound enabled in the Sound System Options.

Any suggestion what might be?

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu, perhaps the other way round of this question. https://askubuntu.com/questions/61878/how-can-i-disable-the-popping-sound-when-adjusting-the-volume?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @SadaharuWakisaka Fixed using this answer https://askubuntu.com/a/455549/1138413 but of course switching it to true.